# Struggling to understand how to manipulate an equation of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Say I have the equation

$x = \vec{a}\cdot(\vec{b}-\vec{c})$,

where $\vec{a}$ is a column vector, $\vec{b}$, and $\vec{c}$ are row vectors, $x$ is a scalar, and $\vec{a}\cdot(\vec{b}-\vec{c})$ is taking the dot product between $\vec{a}$ and $(\vec{b}-\vec{c})$.
Is it possible to solve for $\vec{b}$?

I would naively think I could do this as

$x = \vec{a}\cdot(\vec{b}-\vec{c})$,

$x\vec{a}^T = ||\vec{a}||^2(\vec{b}-\vec{c})$,

$x\vec{a}^T = ||\vec{a}||^2\vec{b}-||\vec{a}||^2\vec{c}$,

$\vec{b} = \frac{x\vec{a}^T + ||\vec{a}||^2\vec{c}}{||\vec{a}||^2}$

But this does not seem correct when putting in concrete values. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the dot between vectors? [This one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product)? Which of the properties there can you use?

Comment: You assume $\vec{a} \cdot (\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}) = (\vec{a} \cdot \vec{a}) \cdot \vec{b}$ which is not true.

Comment: Vector $\vec{b}$ is not unique. You can take $\vec{b}=(0,0,,...,b_i,0,0,..,0)$, where $i$ is any index for which $a_i\neq 0$, $b_i=\frac{x+\vec{a}\cdot\vec{c}}{a_i}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x,\vec{a}$, and $\vec{c}$ are all given then we can rearrange to get $$ \vec{b} \cdot \vec{a} = x + \vec{c}\cdot\vec{a}. $$ This is the equation of a hyperplane in ${\Bbb R}^n$ (assuming that this is where your vectors live). In particular the solution is not unique (as pointed out by Ivan Kaznacheyeu) unless $n=1$.